# How to point p2 Eclipse product update site to local http server?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, updates, httpserver, p2

I want to test p2 update mechanism in my Eclipse RCP project, and I would like my application, to connect to local http server (on `localhost`), and get update from there. I think, I should use Apache server, or something like this. I work on Debian 9. What is the best way to place repository (generated each time I export new version of my product) to some location on `localhost` ?

Comment: The update site can just be a folder of your local file system. Why would you insist on http access?

Comment: Ultimately I want to have a remote http server, from which I can download updates for my client. I just wanted to check, if 'http' option in p2.inf file works.

Comment: Then you're right: you need a web server like Apache or even just a minimal [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to serve the files over http. Alternatively, if you have a NAS with a builtin web server, use that instead of setting up a local web server.